# Glassfish NullPointeException сервер не запускается

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-ee, glassfish

Только скачал архив `GlassFish 5.0 - Full Platform`, разархивировал его, запускаю через командную строку

> asadmin start-domain

и выбивает

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.initializeServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:218)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceLocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:88)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getServiceLocator(CLIContainer.java:217)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getLocalCommand(CLIContainer.java:255)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getCommand(CLICommand.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:371)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:306)
    at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:57)`
```

Пробовал в файле **asenv.bat** установить путь **set path=C:/.../Java/bin** - не помогло.
Пробовал так запустить: **asadmin start-domain domain1** - не помогло.

Установлена: **jdk-9.0.1**
Также пробовал на 8-ой, не помогло. Что делать???

Answer (score 3):

Решение оказалось банальным до ужаса, облазив просторы интернета я обнаружил, что **jdk-9.0.1** тупо не поддерживается (пока что) `GlassFish 5.0 - Full Platform`.
Я установил обратно 8-мую Java и начал тестить. Ошибка оставалась. Пути в системных переменных я поменял с 9 на 8. Но ошибка не уходила.

И тут я решил проверить, а какая версия Java вызывается с коммандной строки. Как оказалось, даже если в переменной Path установлен путь к 8, оно по какой-то причине все равно вызывает 9-ю Java. Перезагрузка не помогла.

Решение - полное удаление 9 джавы.

P.S. иногда выскакивала ошибка:

> your jdk is version 0

Это опять таки из-за несовместимости.